# nodejs, dynamo table get operation callback or async

Tags: performance, node.js, amazon-dynamodb, restify

Folks,
  I am writing an API which gets results from a DynamoDB table, and puts back JSON to the browser.

The code below works, and returns desired results... however, after reading about async and callbacks, its becoming important for me to know if i should be writing this in another way?  Does the following scale well with hundreds of concurrent API callers?

This code does not seem to be using callbacks.  Is it Asynchronous?

```
var restify = require('restify');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'});
var db = new AWS.DynamoDB();

function myFunction(req, res, next) {
  var params = {
    TableName : 'myTable',
    KeyConditions : 
      {
        "number" : 
          {
            "AttributeValueList" : [
              {
                "S" : req.params.simethingid
              }
            ],
            "ComparisonOperator" : "EQ"
          }
      }
  }

  db.query(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      } 
    else {
      res.statusCode = 200;
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8');
      res.send(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2))
      res.end();
      }
  });
  return next();
 }

server.get('/searchme/:somethingid', myFunction);
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean, it's not using callbacks? `db.query` takes a callback as its second parameter. There are many factors that would determine whether it would scale -- just looking at this tiny amount of code isn't enough to make that determination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code you are showing is asynchronous and is using a callback. The function(err, data) {...} in the call to db.query is the callback function.

Notice that in that code your are passing a function definition to db.query() -- db.query will call this function, hence the name callback.

The question of whether this code will "scale well with hundreds of concurrent API callers" cannot be answered in this forum. It's hard/impossible to give you a good answer to this without knowing an excruciating amount of details about your environment.